# WatchKit app second launch causes WatchKit Extension ERROR -[SPRemoteInterface _interfaceControllerClientIDForControllerID:] clientIdentifier

Tags: ios, watchkit

I have a basic watchkit app running on the simulator, which loads a page based navigation with variable number of interface controllers, depending on the settings from the native iOS app.

The interesting thing is that everything works fine during the **first** launch of the app. After stopping the app and launching it again, I get a constant flow of this error:

```
WatchKit Extension[3191:21870] *********** ERROR -[SPRemoteInterface _interfaceControllerClientIDForControllerID:] clientIdentifier for interfaceControllerID:C760002 not found
```

Only after the restart of the machine that I use for development I get the app working again, however, only for the first launch. I think this might be because the Watch Extension process no longer runs and the Watch App attemps to connect to it as [Daniel described in his post](http://daniellam.me/blog/apple-watch-demo-app-and-lessons-learnt/). I might be wrong, but maybe someone has as solution to suggest for such situation?

EDIT

When I debug using some breakpoints in the beginning of watchkit app launch and later after some stops on breakpoints I turn them off and let the app to run, it runs as it should and that error doesn't appear any more. It looks like that giving application some time to get/retrieve some kind of info removes the error. Looks like I might have some problems with threading...

Comment: possible duplicate of [WatchKit reloadRootControllersWithNames causing error, with pageController or after push/pop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28596405/watchkit-reloadrootcontrollerswithnames-causing-error-with-pagecontroller-or-af)

Comment: But how come is that during the first app lauch everything works fine?

Comment: I'm not using hierarchical navigation in my app (no push/pop methods). What I have is one Interface Controller in my storyboard which is replicated n times using reloadRootControllersWithNames:contexts: method with a contexts received from the main iOS app, so if I understand correctly, I'm using ONLY page based navigation...